# artifactory.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: java, linux, artifactory

#### Environment description:

artifactory version: jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.55.2-linux
java version: openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18
system version:
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

#### problem description

artifactory.service restarted every several hours and sometimes artifactory.service will not be functionable.
journalctl -u artifactory.service shows below log

```
2月 22 15:17:25 Artifactory systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=143/n/a
2月 22 15:17:25 Artifactory systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2月 22 15:17:25 Artifactory systemd[1]: Stopped Artifactory service.
2月 22 15:18:14 Artifactory systemd[1]: Starting Artifactory service...
```

#### Things I tried:

1. By checking the console log of /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/console.log, i haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Analysis

Further checking by:

```
# ps -ef --forest | less | grep artifactory
...
-server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -Xms512m -Xmx2g
...
```

By search `OnOutOfMemoryError` got `This option can be used to specify a command or script to execute when an OutOfMemoryError exception is thrown.` in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html
And by executing below found

```
# grep 'OutOfMemoryError' -rn /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log
Binary file /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/artifactory-service.log matches
Binary file /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/archived/artifactory-service.2023-06-08T12-25-37.903.log matches
Binary file /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/archived/console-2023-06-08-1686189301.log matches
Binary file /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/console.log matches
```

And by checking the log found below:

```
[65027.377s][warning][gc,alloc] http-nio-127.0.0.1-8091-Acceptor: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 1026 words
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 10131"...
```

#### Solution:

refer to https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-system-yaml
I changed

```
  #extraJavaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx2g"
```

to

```
  extraJavaOpts: "-Xms50g -Xmx100g"
```

then

```
systemctl restart artifactory.service
```